# Status code 429 on subscribing to Microsoft Graph push notifications

Tags: java, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-api

I'm trying to subscribe to Microsoft Push Notifications and I'm getting status code (429 Too Many Requests) each time I try to call the subscriptions endpoint. According to documentation:

> https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/errors Client application has been throttled and should not attempt to repeat the request until an amount of time has elapsed.

But, Since I tried yesterday and had this error and I try it now and have the same. Probably, the amount of time that I should to wait is not the main cause. The problems appears even if I do a totally separate request without requesting Microsoft Graph for a long time.
Info about the request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
```

Request payload::

```
{
"resource": "me/calendars/{calendarId}/events",
"notificationUrl": "https://{myApp}/office365/notifications/",
"changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
"expirationDateTime": "2017-07-22T08:23:42Z"
}
```

Error:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: 429; Reason:  ]",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "1ed7e537-8524-4a8b-89eb-43501066e7fa",
        "date": "2017-07-19T09:55:27"
    }
}
}
```

What can be the issue here? Migth it give this error due to me trying to subsribe for several times before on the same resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We investigated this request and it is throttling because it is exceeding maximum number of allowed subscriptions.

Comment: What's the maximum?